# Android - How to include and use a ResourceBundle

Tags: android, resourcebundle

My Android app is reliant on 3rd party code.  This code uses resource bundles and put them in a directory called resourcebundles under their src directory.  In their code, they then do this:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("appname.resourcebundles.ErrorBundle");
```

I want to do the same, but am having trouble figuring out where I should put the resource bundles.  I have tried a couple of different places, but always get a mission resource exception.

Any guidance on what I should try?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I just needed "com.appname.resourcebundles.ErrorBundle".  But resource bundles do in fact work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but in my app, I put files in the "assets" directory, which I can then access by

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open(fileName);
```

Where fileName is a string containing the name of your file, like for example "text.txt"

To my knowledge putting stuff in the "assets" directory is the only way to include files and use them like you're saying.  However, it's quite possible that I'm wrong. :-P

Thanks, :-)

-Jared

Comment: Style note: TitleCase is usually reserved for class and interface names in Java.  camelCase is typically used for just about everything else.

Comment: This is a decent suggestion.  I have seen others talk about how they put it in their raw folder.  But, that was a workaround to bugs against android and are now marked as fixed saying that getBundle is working now.  So, I was hoping to use it, but just understand where I should put the bundles.